# Slow MySQL query when datetime between in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, debian

I have a table that takes in a patient satisfaction survey (create statement at bottom) with 17 questions and a few text blocks. It sets a datetime field when the survey is entered into the database. I have to be able to run reports on averages for time periods (weeks/months/years). Currently, I am running queries in weekly slices.

My queries are taking up to 16s to run, and max the CPU during the run. I then have to do that query for 13 more weeks to get a global average, then I do the query 14 **more** times per selected doctor(can be between 0 and 22 times).

I have tried using `WHERE date >= 'date low' AND date <= 'date high'`, `WHERE date BETWEEN 'date low' AND 'date high'`, and I have tried `CAST('date' as datetime)` to no avail. When profiling the query, it seems to spend the bulk of its time on `statistics` and an `EXPLAIN` seems to be saying it is not using the datescanned index, but I don't know why.

There are about 1000 rows currently, but the queries ran fine when there were about half that number of rows. From that, I gather that I have a pretty bad problem with either how I created the table, or how I'm forming my queries.

NOTE: running on Debian 7.2 on VMWare ESXi 5.1 with 4GB mem and 1 virtual proc

**Create Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `survey` (
   `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `datescanned` datetime NOT NULL,
   `physician_fk` int(5) NOT NULL,
   `procedure` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `gender` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
   `patientage` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not marked',
   `question01_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question02_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question03_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question04_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question05_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question06_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question07_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question08_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question09_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question10_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question11_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question12_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question13_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question14_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question15_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question16_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `question17_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `notes` text,
   `email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `qanotes` text,
   `referredby` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `editedby_fk` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `viewed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `handled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `archived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_physicianid` (`physician_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question01id` (`question01_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question02id` (`question02_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question03id` (`question03_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question04id` (`question04_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question05id` (`question05_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question06id` (`question06_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question07id` (`question07_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question08id` (`question08_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question09id` (`question09_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question10id` (`question10_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question11id` (`question11_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question12id` (`question12_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question13id` (`question13_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question14id` (`question14_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question15id` (`question15_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question16id` (`question16_fk`),
    KEY `fk_question17id` (`question17_fk`),
    KEY `fk_editedbyid` (`editedby_fk`),
    KEY `handled` (`handled`),
    KEY `scanned_index` (`datescanned`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=991 ;
```

NOTE: all questions point to the same table

**Select Query**

```
SELECT  q01.worth, q02.worth, q03.worth, q04.worth, q05.worth, q06.worth, q07.worth,
q08.worth, q09.worth, q10.worth, q11.worth, q12.worth, q13.worth, q14.worth, q15.worth,
q16.worth, q17.worth

FROM survey s, answer q01, answer q02, answer q03, answer q04,
answer q05, answer q06, answer q07, answer q08, answer q09, answer q10, answer q11,
answer q12, answer q13, answer q14, answer q15, answer q16, answer q17 

WHERE s.archived !=1 AND q01.id = s.question01_fk AND q02.id = s.question02_fk
AND q03.id = s.question03_fk AND q04.id = s.question04_fk AND q05.id = s.question05_fk
AND q06.id = s.question06_fk AND q07.id = s.question07_fk AND q08.id = s.question08_fk 
AND q09.id = s.question09_fk AND q10.id = s.question10_fk AND q11.id = s.question11_fk 
AND q12.id = s.question12_fk AND q13.id = s.question13_fk AND q14.id = s.question14_fk
AND q15.id = s.question15_fk AND q16.id = s.question16_fk AND q17.id = s.question17_fk

AND s.datescanned >=  '2013-11-18 00:00:00' AND s.datescanned <=  '2013-11-25 23:59:59';
```

NOTE: I have tried with and without INNER JOINs for the question_fk

EDIT: It has been brought to my attention that I need to rethink my structure. I will work on that and either update or close this post if that fixes it. Thank you to those who have commented so far.

EDIT 2: It was a structure problem. Splitting out the questions and mapping to them dropped the full report to under 20 seconds, from over 3 minutes. Thank you everyone who provided guidance.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data. A database table IS NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: You have a hidden many-to-many relationship between survey and questions. That means you should add an extra table to handle those relationships

Comment: @MostyMostacho So, some form of id, survey_id, question_01, ..., question_17?

Comment: One table `surveys` with a primary key `id`, and one table `questions` with a foreign key `survey_id`. Every time you have `foo1`, `foo2`, `fooN` is a sign that you need two tables with the `foo` table having a foreign key.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for the explanation, I am going to work on that now.

Comment: You might also look at a NoSQL system like [Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/). It seems more appropriate for the kind of data you're storing.

Comment: No, a nosql database is a REALLY BAD IDEA if you don't understand database design. It's a REALLY BAD IDEA if you want to combine OLTP and reporting. It's a REALLY BAD IDEA if you don't understand how to analyse and resolve performance issues.

Comment: Where is the exaplin plan for the query? Where are the table and index stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not technically answering the question, this is the design I would use:

- SURVEY: **survey_id**, datescanned, etc...
- QUESTION: **question_id**, description, etc...
- SURVEY_QUESTION: **survey_id**, **question_id**

In bold you can see the primary keys. Note the `SURVEY_QUESTION` table has a compound key containing both the foreign key to `SURVEY` and the foreign key to `QUESTION`.

In order to get all surveys with all questions you should do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM survey s
JOIN survey_question sq on s.survey_id = sq.survey_id
JOIN question q on sq.question_id = q.question_id
```

That should be faster and much more flexible than having one column per question.

Comment: After your's and other's comments, that was were I was going as well. Will report back.

Comment: Well, as far as my testing can show, structure was my problem. I have implemented a system like you described and am now running two searches, one to get the list of survey id's then another to get the answers for those id's. doing a combination has dropped my tests down to less than 20 seconds for the full report (global avg, and 20+ dr. specific reports.) Thank you for your guidance!